# Getting a ton of notifications when going back from airplane mode

Tags: notifications, facebook-messenger, samsung-galaxy-s-9, airplane-mode

When I disable airplane mode, I get all notifications for events that occurred while the phone had been offline. Typically that would be a couple of hundred Facebook messenger messages. The phone sounds like a machine gun for a while when it plays the notification sound repeatedly.

Is there a way to turn that off?

Comment: Use the "Do not disturb" mode

Comment: So I enable that before turning off flightmode then?

Comment: Exactly. Than the notification sound should be silenced.

Comment: But there is no way to have that builtin into "turn off flightmode"?

Comment: Or try automation. For example, with [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), create a macro like [this](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZocLlXZOiQ1duBXWXjWyEmyU4kELjaVQpR7) (download macro to test) //This records your notification volume level when you put on aeroplane mode and when you disable aeroplane mode, it reduces notification volume to 0 for 2 minutes (configurable) for your machine gun to stop :) and then restores to earlier volume level //I haven't tested, hence as a comment than answer

Comment: Correction - download and import Macro into the app

Comment: are you aware of android native app notification settings? just block such spamming apps completely, or disable sound at least

Comment: But I never asked how to get rid of notifications or sound. @alecxs